# MongoDB Script with rs.add() Not Executing As Expected

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset

For some reason this very basic script does not run as expected:

```
rs.initiate();
rs.add("ip-10-0-1-11");
rs.add("ip-10-0-1-12");
```

When I call it (after a fresh spin-up of mongod) like so:

```
docker exec mongodb mongo localhost:27017/test /script/path.js
```

I only see the addition of the second host.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-12-14T20:27:10.124Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(1),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "ip-10-0-1-10:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 45,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1450124790, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-12-14T20:26:30Z"),
                        "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1450124789, 2),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-12-14T20:26:29Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 2,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "ip-10-0-1-12:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 40,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1450124790, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-12-14T20:26:30Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-12-14T20:27:09.828Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-12-14T20:27:06.827Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "configVersion" : 2
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

However, if I jump back into the cli and add the missing host manually - it works no problem. Also - if I just run the script again, the second one gets added as normal.

Checking the logs doesn't give me back any useful information. I just see that the `ip-10-0-1-12` host was added, and no references to `ip-10-0-1-11`. I'm 100% certain the other mongod instance is reachable by the time I run these commands.

I have tried this a few ways - even like so:

```
docker exec mongodb mongo localhost:27017/test --eval 'rs.initiate();rs.add("ip-10-0-1-11");rs.add("ip-10-0-1-12");'
```

As well as jumping into the cli and running `load("path/to/script.js")`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Here is a chunk of logs while the script ran. Everything above is initialization info, and everything below is just accepted connections:

```
2015-12-14T20:26:29.759+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1] initiate : no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set
2015-12-14T20:26:29.759+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1] created this configuration for initiation : { _id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "ip-10-0-1-10:27017" } ] }
2015-12-14T20:26:29.759+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetInitiate admin command received from client
2015-12-14T20:26:29.759+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetInitiate config object with 1 members parses ok
2015-12-14T20:26:29.759+0000 I REPL     [conn1] ******
2015-12-14T20:26:29.759+0000 I REPL     [conn1] creating replication oplog of size: 990MB...
2015-12-14T20:26:29.765+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1] Starting WiredTigerRecordStoreThread local.oplog.rs
2015-12-14T20:26:29.765+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 0 records totaling to 0 bytes
2015-12-14T20:26:29.765+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1] Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
2015-12-14T20:26:29.784+0000 I REPL     [conn1] ******
2015-12-14T20:26:29.793+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] New replica set config in use: { _id: "rs0", version: 1, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "ip-10-0-1-10:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 } } }
2015-12-14T20:26:29.793+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] This node is ip-10-0-1-10:27017 in the config
2015-12-14T20:26:29.793+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to STARTUP2
2015-12-14T20:26:29.793+0000 I REPL     [conn1] Starting replication applier threads
2015-12-14T20:26:29.794+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to RECOVERING
2015-12-14T20:26:29.795+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetReconfig admin command received from client
2015-12-14T20:26:29.795+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to SECONDARY
2015-12-14T20:26:29.795+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected
2015-12-14T20:26:29.795+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] dry election run succeeded, running for election
2015-12-14T20:26:29.803+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] election succeeded, assuming primary role in term 1
2015-12-14T20:26:29.803+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to PRIMARY
2015-12-14T20:26:29.804+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetReconfig admin command received from client
2015-12-14T20:26:29.806+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetReconfig config object with 2 members parses ok
2015-12-14T20:26:29.807+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to ip-10-0-1-12:27017
2015-12-14T20:26:29.808+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] New replica set config in use: { _id: "rs0", version: 2, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "ip-10-0-1-10:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 1, host: "ip-10-0-1-12:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 } } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rs.initiate() requires a few seconds for the replica to change status. This might cause the first rs.add() not working properly. It's strange that we did not get an error message for this.

To avoid this problem happens, you can try to initiate and configure all the members in replica set in a single command:

```
rs.initiate(
  {_id:'rs0',
   members:[ { _id:1, host:'ip-10-0-1-10:27017'},
             { _id:2, host:'ip-10-0-1-11:27017'},
             { _id:3, host:'ip-10-0-1-12:27017'}]
   });
```